# what is CPP_LINK in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

what is `CPP_LINK` in make file. I did google regarding that, but didn't get any satisfactory answer.

In addition to that I came across some flags like `-Wl`, `-rpath`. What are these flags ?

Operating system: CentOS 5.7
g++ version: 4.1.2

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in variable CPP_LINK stored path to linker. Program for make executable file from obj code. Object code files you got from C++ compiler :)

This is common answer. In your question not presented infromation about your OS and about your C++ version.

Comment: For linux system used gcc as linker. Just run `gcc --help` in terminal for get list of options. For example `-Wl,<options> Pass comma-separated <options> on to the linker`